# Retrieve / read data from Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this code to retrieve data from a Firebase database. However, I am only able to pull one variable at a time. Can you please help me find a way to pull the others (student names, title etc.) and save them to an object arrayList?

```
{
  "projects" : [ 
     1, {
        "answer1" : false,
        "answer2" : true,
        "answer3" : true,
        "campus" : "Science Academy",
        "category" : "LifeScience",
        "question1" : "This is question 1",
        "question2" : "This is question 2",
        "question3" : "This is question 3",
        "student1" : "john",
        "student2" : "Kyle",
        "title" : "Amazon Forest"
        }
   ]
 }


var ref : DatabaseReference?
var handle : DatabaseHandle?


    ref = Database.database().reference()
    handle = ref?.child("projects").child("1").child(question1).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let question = snapshot.value as? String {
            print(question)
        }
    })
```

Comment: I don't see why you need access to his database @KhawarIslam . His database structure is included in the question

Comment: I don't know swift, so I can't help much. Have a look at the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

Comment: I don't need the access of database, i need only URL. Because i want to iterate the elements one by one.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the child values of the *1* node? So you want to get to the values with the keys answer1, category etc? If so, the first issue is that you appear to be using an array to store data in Firebase and that may lead to a lot of other problems. Secondly, the code you included will only read the value of the question1 key. Oh. and you do NOT need to provide your DB URL - that's a silly request for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your database has more that just `projects/1` and you're wanting to access projects/1-2-3-4 etc. then you'll want to do something like this:

```
    let reference = Database.database().reference()
    reference.child("projects").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key // THIS WILL GET THE PROJECT THAT IT'S IN. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

        let answer1 = dictionary["answer1"] as? Bool
        let campus = dictionary["campus"] as? String

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

IF you're wanting to simple get a hold of all the values inside of `project/1` and not just the questions, you'll want to do something like this:

```
    let reference = Database.database().reference()
    reference.child("projects").child("1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key // THIS WILL GET THE PROJECT THAT IT'S IN. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

        let answer1 = dictionary["answer1"] as? Bool
        let campus = dictionary["campus"] as? String

    }, withCancel: nil)
```